# Disapprove password if it contains exactly 4 digits (validation)

Tags: python, regex, validation

I can't figure out how to modify my regex to make sure the password follows the last condition:

- at least 2 capital letters in a row
- doesn't have space symbols
- contains digits
- doesn't contain 4 consecutive digits

{4} It currently disapproves the password if it has 4 and more digits but I need it to disapprove the password with EXACTLY 4 digits.

```
s1 = 'annII#443'
s2 = 'annII#4343'
s3 = 'annII#43434'

pattern = r"^(?=.*[A-Z]{2,})(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?!.*[0-9]{4})(?!.*[\s]).*$"

re.findall(pattern, s1) # ['aШnnII#443']
re.findall(pattern, s2) # []
re.findall(pattern, s3) # []
```

PS: It's just a task so don't worry. It's not gonna be used for any real purposes.

Comment: so, what exactly is wrong?

Comment: Do you mean `^(?=.*[A-Z]{2,})(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?!.*[0-9]{4})(?!.* ).*$` (note the space `' '` character instead `\s`

Comment: edited the post. i want the pattern to only ban s2, not s2 and s3 (and other strings which contain 4+ digits

Comment: I feel like it's worth mentioning that those are *terrible* password constraints. Why on Earth would you forbid spaces, or 4 numbers in a row, or require two capital letters? Absolutely bonkers. And why, in year of our Lord 2022, are you trying to roll your own password management?

Comment: @JaredSmith - While I agree with the basic sentiment (not the delivery); it would be more helpful to give examples of *good* constraints, rather than vaguely criticise the current constraints. Why roll your own? Educational purposes. Excellent way to learn the core fundamental.

Comment: @S3DEV I agree with your sentiment and would like to give a nudge in a better direction, but that's arguably too large a topic for an SO *answer*, much less an SO comment. [I guess linking this](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Authentication_Cheat_Sheet.html) is probably a good place for the OP to start.

Comment: @sasha - Generally, password validation is done as a series of rules.  If *all* rules pass, the password is accepted for use.  This is not generally done using a single regex.

Comment: To address your point of confusion directly, strings that contain 5 numbers in a row also contain 4 numbers in a row. If you only want that part of the regex to find exactly 4 numbers without any other numbers next to them, you'll have to do something like this `(?!.*(?<![0-9])[0-9]{4}(?![0-9]))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. To match exactly four digits, you can use at *start* `^` e.g. `(?!(?:.*\D)?\d{4}(?!\d))`.
   This requires *start* or a `\D` [non-digit](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html#negated) before the 4 digits and disallows a digit after.
2. `(?=.*[A-Za-z])` looks redundant if you already require `(?=.*[A-Z]{2,})` (2 upper).
3. `{2,}` two *or more* is redundant. `{2}` would suffice and does not change the logic.
4. Instead of `(?!.*[\s]).*$` you can just use `\S*$` (upper matches *non-whitespaces*).
5. It's generally more efficient to use [lazy](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#lazy_solution) `.*?` or even a [negated class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) where possible.

```
^(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z]{2})(?=\D*\d)(?!(?:.*\D)?\d{4}(?!\d))\S*$
```

[See this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/hurgX7/1) (added `\n` to negations in multiline demo for staying in line)